# Need help for deserializing a json format

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I'm trying to get the Java class for deserializing this:
[API Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTREL.png)
I'm using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ for getting the java classes I need. But with this json response I get this:

```
public class CatalogueResponse {
 @SerializedName("0")
    @Expose
    private uex.asee.fjrm.multimediapp.api.pojos.catalogue._0 _0;
    @SerializedName("1")
    @Expose
    private uex.asee.fjrm.multimediapp.api.pojos.catalogue._1 _1;
    @SerializedName("2")
    @Expose
    private uex.asee.fjrm.multimediapp.api.pojos.catalogue._2 _2;
    @SerializedName("3")
    @Expose
    private uex.asee.fjrm.multimediapp.api.pojos.catalogue._3 _3;
    @SerializedName("4")
    @Expose
    private uex.asee.fjrm.multimediapp.api.pojos.catalogue._4 _4;
    @SerializedName("5")
    @Expose
    private uex.asee.fjrm.multimediapp.api.pojos.catalogue._5 _5;
    ...
}
```

But the number of items of the json is varying, so I can't handle it that way.
I'm using gson annotations by the way.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can I see your java json schema?

Comment: Do not understand the whole problem, just a suggestion about the API : if the number of items vary, but all the items are the same, you should use a JSON array :)

Comment: Yes, @mithrop is right. This is way a was asking for your json schema

Comment: Do you wish to serialize or deserialize this JSON?

Comment: The API is not mine, so I can't change the JSON it gave to me. And yes, what i want is deserialize the json, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try using a Map and then serializing it. I would suggest using a TreeMap and adding numbers as keys and values as the Catalogue object. Something like:

```
Map<Integer, Catalogue> map = new TreeMap<>();
map.put(0, catalogue0);
map.put(1, catalogue1);
...
// Now serialize the map.
```

This will generate the API response that you require.

To deserialize it using Gson, try the following:

```
Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<Integer, Catalogue>>(){}.getType();
Map<Integer, Catalogue> catalogueMap = (Map<Integer, Catalogue>) gson.fromJson(json, mapType);
```

Comment: Sorry, what i really wanted is deserialize the json. I said it wrong, sorry.

Comment: This looks like the correct approach, but your example is for Jackson instead if gson which javi said he was using

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I didn't see that

Comment: I really apreciate your help, but maybe i should have mentioned that i'm using retrofit, so i have an interface 
 and I set before an request interceptor with the Gson.Builder http://imgur.com/a/dzroo

Comment: You should look into [JsonDeserializer](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Finally got it working this way http://prntscr.com/950yf6. But now I need handle something inside the CatalogueItem Object. Am i supposed to do it in that method too or do i need to create another deserializer. I'm asking it because i tried to register a new adapter for the CatalogueItem.class but gson don't use it. Maybe because its not a Response one?